# Button syncronized with thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, button, onresume, onpause

How create a button which pause the thread which is inside the loop and another button which 
resumes.

```
Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
```

public void run(){

```
   for(int j =0 ;j<=words.length;j++){

       synchronized(this){
           try {

                wait(sleepTime);

                bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                try {
                                    wait();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                    }});
                bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        notify();

                    }
                });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } }
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               try {
                    et.setText(words[i]);
                    i++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }});
      }}};
```

doing some stuff say words.lenght=1000 times
then suppose user want to take break in between
click pause button with id = bt this button pauses   thread until and user 
clicks resume with id= bt1

Comment: Handler will suit for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Below is a hint , i think you can use for your problem. Its copied from the link i pasted at end.

A wait can be "woken up" by another process calling notify on the monitor which is being waited on whereas a sleep cannot. Also a wait (and notify) must happen in a block synchronized on the monitor object whereas sleep does not:

```
Object mon = ...;
synchronized (mon) {
    mon.wait();
}
```

At this point the currently executing thread waits and releases the monitor. Another thread may do

synchronized (mon) { mon.notify(); }(On the same mon object) and the first thread (assuming it is the only thread waiting on the monitor) will wake up.

Check [Difference between wait() and sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

[How to indefinitely pause a thread in Java and later resume it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622804/how-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread-in-java-and-later-resume-it)

Only you call the `suspend()` and other methods from your buttons' `OnClickListener`s